# Should I use guards instead of resolvers to save rendering cycles in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I'm building upon the experience with a previous large scale angular 2 app. I've been really careful to keep the rendering cycles under control. Keeping a log is how I investigate what happens.

**Controller**

```
public debugTemplate() {
    DEBUG.render && debug('Render FooCmp');
}
```

**Template**

```
{{ debugTemplate() }}
```

I've been using only ngrx state store subscriptions in the smart components. This way I can avoid completely the need of using `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` or `RouteReuseStrategy`

**Guard**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
    RouterStateSnapshot  } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { DEBUG } from '../../../config/config';
import * as Debug from 'debug';

// Interfaces
import { Foo } from '../interfaces/foo';

// Services
import { BarService } from '../services/bar.service';
import { FooService } from '../services/foo.service';

// Debug
const debugOff = (...any) => { }, debug = Debug('app:FooPageGuard');

@Injectable()
export class FooPageGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        private _barService: BarService,
        private _fooService: FooService
    ) {
        DEBUG.constr && debug('Construct FooPageGuard');
    }

    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean> {
        DEBUG.guard && debug('Guard FooPageGuard');

        return this._fooService.foo$().switchMap(
            foo => this._barService.getBar(foo)
        )
        .map(data => { if (data) {return true} })
        .first() // Take first and enable the route
        .do(foo => DEBUG.guard && debug('Guard OK FooPageGuard:', foo)) 

    }
}
```

**Smart component** with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

```
// Ngrx state store subscription
this._fooService.foo$().subscribe(exp => this.foo = exp);
```

Using `ng serve --prod --aot` I've been able to see that the rendering of parent components is executed onlz once if I use guards instead of resolvers. Using resolvers leads to multiple renderings to get the same initial state. In the Angular documentation guards are recommended for login and resolvers for data retrieval. Looks like this comes at the cost of multiple wasteful renderings if you have lots of streams of data getting resolved async.

So the question. Is it ok to bypass this convention? Using ngrx state store subscription and ditching resolvers + route subscription in the component in favor of guards that trigger the data request.

Another strange behavior is that no matter what I do initally I still have a few `AppCmp` renderings which seem to be triggered by the observables themselves before the children comps are even `Init`ed.

**Edit**

I just had some trouble today. It was a mistake to use `OnPush` for container components such as pages (smart components). The subscriptions will fire but the template will not receive the updated values. That's expected from OnPush since no inputs are triggered. So I'm using OnPush only on the dumb components, which is still a significant improvement since they do the bulk of the hard work.

**Edit 2 - Use resolvers, not guards**

Well... This didn't work out as expected. Let's just say that if you have an observable that hasn't fired yet, the guard will simply block the flow permanently. So my fancy example was working just because the observables had already some values inside that mapped to a true. After doing a thorough cleanup I found that my app stopped working.

In essence, the following basic example works within a resolver but not a guard. This is because the observable can't get any value back the moment he asks for it so he just assumes it's a no go. I'll just have to investigate further where are those extra renderings coming from. There must be some faulty code somewhere.

```
return  Observable.interval(1000)
    .take(1) // Needed to trigger the guard. Resolvers do just fine without
    .map(() => true )
```

Comment: My opinion, if it works it's ok. The only thing you might want to add is wrap the code in the guard in a named method like fecthTheData, so someone else can see it's not really 'guard code'. But, what's the difference between the resolver code and the guard code? Is resolver getting called multiple times? What happens when not using AOT, i.e is the resolver 'bug' peculiar to AOT?

Comment: Building ahead of time helps disable the double check in angular command line. Since I havenät ejected webpack config I prefer this way. Withouts the double check it is possible to see onlz the real renderings. I agree with `fecthTheData` I was plannign to do so. SOmehow the guard seems to execute the observables until they all finish and then render unlinke the resolver which renders for each observable firing.

Comment: That's interesting. The switchMap is a novel idea to 'nest' the observables (I presume that's why it's there). I just subscribe to the first and call the next inside subscribe, but of course that's slower. Looking at my own resolve code, I can't think why the observables would behave differently in there - the rxjs stuff should be consistent in different places.

Comment: @AdrianMoisa You should post your edit2 findings as an answer to the question, instead of as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use resolvers, not guards**

Well... This didn't work out as expected. Let's just say that if you have an observable that hasn't fired yet, the guard will simply block the flow permanently. So my fancy example was working just because the observables had already some values inside that mapped to a true. After doing a thorough cleanup I found that my app stopped working.

In essence, the following basic example works within a resolver but not a guard. This is because the observable can't get any value back the moment he asks for it so he just assumes it's a no go. I'll just have to investigate further where are those extra renderings coming from. There must be some faulty code somewhere.

```
return  Observable.interval(1000)
    .take(1) // Needed to trigger the guard. Resolvers do just fine without
    .map(() => true )
```